# video autoplay is not working in my android version marshmallow

Tags: php, html, html5-video, android-6.0-marshmallow, autoplay

I need a video auto play in some part of my website ,but the video is not working in my android marshmallow.

Below is my code.

```html
  <video   width="100%" height="30%" autoplay    src="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT . 'files/youtube-video/' . $newName; ?>" ></video>
```

Give me some idea ,how can i fix it ,so that the video will play with page load .no extra event  fire is required .

Thank you ,any suggestion will be highly appreciated .

Comment: check if any errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php in php and view html source and use var_dump().

Comment: ok @Fred -ii.....

Comment: No error is coming ,but its showing something 32759 in the place of video box.@Fred -ii

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why `autoplay` param doesn't work on your device, but you can try to  add small JS function to your page which will play video.

Example of playing video on page load with pure js:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    vid.play();
});
```

P.S It will help only in case you see video on the page and can play it manually, it you don't ether your HTML code of video or video's url are not correct.

Comment: No its not working .
My video is not playing when I am loading a page.

Comment: So the issue is not autoplay, show HTML code of your video, when it already rendered (directly from browser) and I will try to help.

Comment: <video id="video1" autoplay  width="" height="" autoplay="" class="create-gif__image js--videopreview" src="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT . 'files/youtube-video/' . $newName; ?>">
                            </video>

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var vid = document.getElementById("video1");
    vid.play();
});});

Comment: This is php code: "<?php echo HTTP_ROOT . 'files/youtube-video/' . $newName; ?>" do you see it in your browser? it should be executed on server in .php/.phtml/etc file and result should be rendered in browser.